# javascript syntax for keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn javascript and I cannot figure out what's wrong with the following simple code.

```
function typeCatch() {
    alert("key pressed");
}

$(function () {
    $("textarea.redactor_editor").on("keypress", typeCatch);
});
```

Basically you would get an alert message everytime you write something in the provided form.

1. What's wrong with this code? `typeCatch()` isn't called when I'm typing in the form.
2. How would I debug this if a similar problem happened? Nothing shows up in the console box in firebug.

http://jsfiddle.net/4wmup/1/

Comment: Your fiddle didn't include jQuery....[include jQuery, works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Arhxd/).

Comment: jQuery's a library  that you need to include (i.e. it's not a language in itself) - in your actual HTML you'd need to include something like `<script type="application/ecmascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` of your HTML, before any other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is using JQuery.  Try setting the JSFiddle to one of the JQuery libraries instead of just Javascript.  (Top-left of the screen)

Cheers, LC

Answer (score 1):

Is your textarea actually a rich text editor, using some other library (like redactor)?

Rich text editors usually hide the actual textarea, and show you a rich text interface that they create instead - so you're not actually typing in the textarea.

Depending on which rich text editor you're using, there may be a different (supported) way to hook in a keypress event handler.